# How to camel route test spring bean with mockito mocked bean

Tags: spring, unit-testing, apache-camel, mockito

I would like to be able to test a route which consumes from a queue then does some work in a bean involving a spring injected service and use mockito to effectively mock out this service.

My spring route is as follows:

```
    <camel:route id="msgemailqueue-to-emailservice">        
        <camel:from uri="activemq:emails" />
        <camel:bean ref="emailService" method="createEmailRequest"/>            
    </camel:route>
```

The emailService bean has an autowired service which is then called in the createEmailRequest() which goes off to another service and retrieves user data to be used subsequently.

The test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TroubledEmailServiceImplTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Produce(context = "messagingCamelContext")
    protected ProducerTemplate producer;

    @Mock
    private UserRestService userRestService;

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("messaging-camel-route-test-context.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserResponseToEmailQueue() throws Exception {
        context.addRoutes(new MyDynamcRouteBuilder(context, "direct:addEmailRequest", "activemq:emails"));

        Mockito.when(userRestService.getUserById(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(
            new WebServiceResult<UserVO>(new UserVO()));

        CreateMessageRequest msgReq = new CreateMessageRequest();
        producer.sendBody("direct:addEmailRequest", msgReq);

        Mockito.verify(userRestService).getUserById(Mockito.anyLong());
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
   }
```

The bean as follows:

```
@Override
public void createEmailRequest(final CreateMessageRequest request) throws CreateEmailException {

    LOGGER.trace("Entering createEmailRequest(request) " + Arrays.asList(new Object[] { request }));

    Validate.notNull(request, "CreateMessageRequest was null");

    WebServiceResult<UserVO> response;
    try {
        response = userRestService.getUserById(request.getId());
    } catch (final WebServiceException e) {
        throw new CreateEmailException("Error lookup up user data for email", e);
    }

    final UserVO userResponse = response.getData();
```

All compiles ok and when running the route fires as an object is popped on the queue which is then passed to the bean and the createEmailRequest is invoked and the call to the mockito mocked service happens ok

```
response = userRestService.getUserById(request.getId());
```

but the response is null even though

```
        Mockito.when(userRestService.getUserById(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(
            new WebServiceResult<UserVO>(new UserVO()));
```

was performed in the test.  It appears that the service in bean is a different instance i.e. mockito mock is never invoked.

I am doing something wrong and perhaps my testing approach is all wrong as well but should this work in theory?  I'd really like to be able to mock out a service in a bean in my camel route.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using **Camel Enhanced Spring Test** and have passed through the same issue. I only changed `@Mock` to `@MockBean`. My Camel version is 2.18.

Answer (score 1):

the mock userRestService you create in the test has to be the same instance you use in the bean.  I do not see where you are setting the userRestService for the createEmailRequest method.  That service needs to be the same mock object as you create in your test.

Comment: Sorry it is autowired in the bean.

    @Autowired
    private UserRestService userRestService;

When debugging in eclipse the userRestService is a Mockito instance - UserRestService$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$31de7f69 **id=72** when setUserRestService() called but UserRestService$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$31de7f69 **id=132** when inside the createEmailRequest() method.  I'm sure the id value in eclipse is not significant but interestingly the toString differs- "Mock for UserRestService, hashCode: 4221046" when the camel route runs it and 'UserRestService' when spring calls the setter.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this - mea culpa.  My test class was effectively creating two instances of the service - one through the spring application context and another due to the @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) plus @mock annotation.  Now resolved by doing the mock creation once.  To sum up this was a spring wiring issue only on my part.  Many thanks @mike-pone.